# Is this way of using Naive Bayes in matlab correct

Tags: matlab, classification, bayesian-networks

I'm using naive bayes in matlab for clasification like this:

```
dataFull = csvread('haberman.data.data')
dataTaining = dataFull(250, :)
dataTaining = dataFull(1:250,:)
dataTest = dataFull(251:end, :)
dataTainingClass = dataTaining(:,4)
dataTraining = dataTraining(:,1:3)
dataTraining = dataTaining(:,1:3)
dataTestClass = dataTest(:,4)
dataTest = dataTest(:,1:3)
nb = NaiveBayes.fit(dataTraining, dataTainingClass)
predict(nb, dataTest)
percentange = (dataTestClass == ans)
sum(percentange) / length(percentange)
```

With Haberman's dataset from UCI [dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/haberman/)

Am I doing this right?

Comment: do you get results you expect?

Comment: I get some results, but I'm not sure if they are correct, because I get 73% right, when in another dataset I got 98% thats is weird

Comment: Depending on the data you are training on and how it randomly splits the data when creating a classifier, you can get vastly different results